# Is filtering useful here, and if so how to choose the value(s)?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscilloscope, self-induction

Simple question of this project:

Is filtering useful here, and if so how to choose the value for L1/L2/L3 - especially L1?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH3Eq2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Context**

This will be the *output* of the project. The idea is to build a simple temperature sensor for oscilloscope display.

The [HPR105](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/281/tdc_hpr1xx-15453.pdf) is an isolated switch mode power supply.  I think it generate some noise on its outputs. I think an output resistor for OP77 would be a good idea too.

The OP77 has very good performance for this use-case, but I have it in stock.

Comment: Whether filtering is useful or not depends on how much noise is acceptable.

Comment: Realize that any L-C series circuit can be a potential **resonating** circuit. If I designed this, I would remove the inductors and I would keep the 100 nF capacitors.

Comment: They can make things worse if not chosen properly. Not like caps where you can usually just keep piling them on and things, at worst, usually stay the same. *Low* resistors are actually safer to use there.

Comment: *HPR105 is, basically some sort of transformer* You mean: isolated DCDC converter. It has a transformer inside but from the outside it does not behave as a transformer. It is usually a good idea to add capacitors across the input of a DCDC converter. *I guess it should generate some noise to outputs* Yes, **nothing** is without noise. The question is, will the noise disturb anything. My guess is that it will not as long as you remove the inductors. I'm guessing you're a beginner so you worry about too much about noise. Just ignore noise, build this thing (without L1-3) and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks to you all, So If I don't need very high precision, (*and I do not*), I can ignore L1;L2 & L3. I will do so.